# I get installation errors when trying to install gatsby

Tags: node.js, npm, gatsby

when trying to install gatsby, i am given the following:

```
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: joi is leaving the @hapi organization and moving back to 'joi' (https://github.com/sideway/joi/issues/2411)
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm WARN express-graphql@0.9.0 requires a peer of graphql@^14.4.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

i have node installed at the latest version. i've tried looking on tutorials, but can't find anything to fix this. how do i resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried removing the project and trying a fresh install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have permissions to the folder where the installation happens. You can add yourself to the folder's permissions and it should run.

You can see who has the permissions to the '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' folder as stated in your error message by running:

```
ls -la /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Here you probably see something like thing:

```
drwxr-xr-x   3 root    wheel   96 Mar 23 13:57 .
drwxrwxr-x  24 someusr admin  768 Mar 23 16:12 ..
drwxr-xr-x  24 root    wheel  768 Feb 23 01:21 npm
```

And we see that not everything within that folder as owned by 'someusr'.

To solve this, you can set the permissions of contents within that folder, to yourself. You can use the chown command with the -R flag to recursively set the permissions of that folder, in combination with environment variable $USER, which will output the current user ('someusr' in this example):

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

And then run the installation command again:

```
npm install -g gatsby-cli
```

Good luck!